# Is it possible to evaluate analytically the following nontrivial triple integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

In a physical mathematical problem, I came across a nontrivial triple integral below obtained upon 3D inverse Fourier transformation. It would be great if someone here could provide with some hints that could help to evaluate analytically
$$
I =\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty \int_0^{\pi}
  \frac{\sin\theta \sin^2\phi}{a \cos^2 \theta + b \sin^2 \theta} \, e^{ikh\sin\theta\cos\phi}  \, \mathrm{d} \theta \, \mathrm{d} k \, \mathrm{d} \phi \, .
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are two positive real numbers.
Using the change of variable $q=\cos\theta$, the latter equation can be written as
$$
I = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty \int_{-1}^{1} 
  \frac{\sin^2\phi}{(a-b)q^2+b} \, e^{ikh\sqrt{1-q^2}\cos\phi} \,  \mathrm{d} q \, \mathrm{d} k \, \mathrm{d} \phi \, .
$$

A guess solution using Maple for some numerical values for $a$ and $b$ is obtained as
$$
I = \frac{1}{4\pi h \sqrt{ab}} \, .
$$

But, is there a way to prove that really? Any idea / feedback is welcome.

Thanks a lot!

Fede

Comment: An analogous (double) integral has been solve previously in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283745/is-it-possible-to-evaluate-analytically-the-following-double-integral

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the first integral we have:

$$\mathscr{I}:=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)\cdot\sin^2\left(\phi\right)\cdot\exp\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\cdot\cos\left(\phi\right)\cdot\text{k}\cdot\text{h}\cdot i\right)}{\text{a}\cdot\cos^2\left(\theta\right)+\text{b}\cdot\sin^2\left(\theta\right)}\space\text{d}\theta\space\text{d}\text{k}\space\text{d}\phi\tag1$$

Using [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem):

$$\mathscr{I}:=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)\cdot\sin^2\left(\phi\right)\cdot\exp\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\cdot\cos\left(\phi\right)\cdot\text{k}\cdot\text{h}\cdot i\right)}{\text{a}\cdot\cos^2\left(\theta\right)+\text{b}\cdot\sin^2\left(\theta\right)}\space\text{d}\text{k}\space\text{d}\theta\space\text{d}\phi=$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)\cdot\sin^2\left(\phi\right)}{\text{a}\cdot\cos^2\left(\theta\right)+\text{b}\cdot\sin^2\left(\theta\right)}\int_0^\infty\exp\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\cdot\cos\left(\phi\right)\cdot\text{k}\cdot\text{h}\cdot i\right)\space\text{d}\text{k}\space\text{d}\theta\space\text{d}\phi\tag2$$

Now, we can use:

$$\int_0^\infty\exp\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\cdot\cos\left(\phi\right)\cdot\text{k}\cdot\text{h}\cdot i\right)\space\text{d}\text{k}=\frac{i}{\sin\left(\theta\right)\cdot\cos\left(\phi\right)\cdot\text{h}}\tag3$$

when $\Im\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\cdot\cos\left(\phi\right)\cdot\text{h}\right)>0$

So, we get:

$$\mathscr{I}=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)\cdot\sin^2\left(\phi\right)}{\text{a}\cdot\cos^2\left(\theta\right)+\text{b}\cdot\sin^2\left(\theta\right)}\cdot\frac{i}{\sin\left(\theta\right)\cdot\cos\left(\phi\right)\cdot\text{h}}\space\text{d}\theta\space\text{d}\phi=$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2\left(\phi\right)\cdot i}{\cos\left(\phi\right)\cdot\text{h}}\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)}{\text{a}\cdot\cos^2\left(\theta\right)+\text{b}\cdot\sin^2\left(\theta\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin\left(\theta\right)}\space\text{d}\theta\space\text{d}\phi=$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2\left(\phi\right)\cdot i}{\cos\left(\phi\right)\cdot\text{h}}\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{\text{a}\cdot\cos^2\left(\theta\right)+\text{b}\cdot\sin^2\left(\theta\right)}\space\text{d}\theta\space\text{d}\phi\tag4$$

Now, use:

$$\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{\text{a}\cdot\cos^2\left(\theta\right)+\text{b}\cdot\sin^2\left(\theta\right)}\space\text{d}\theta=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\text{a}\cdot\text{b}}}\tag5$$

So, we get:

$$\mathscr{I}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2\left(\phi\right)\cdot i}{\cos\left(\phi\right)\cdot\text{h}}\cdot\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\text{a}\cdot\text{b}}}\space\text{d}\phi=\frac{\pi\cdot i}{\text{h}\cdot\sqrt{\text{a}\cdot\text{b}}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2\left(\phi\right)}{\cos\left(\phi\right)}\space\text{d}\phi\tag6$$

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. But PV of the last integral is identically null. Does it mean that $I= 0 $ ? thanks

Comment: I think that it shouldn't. The integral has a physical interpretation and should be strictly positive defined. The guess solution has been proved to be true using Maple but I don't know how to prove it. Indeed, your solution shows the desired $h\sqrt{ab}$ in the denominator. I think that the correct solution should not be that far...

Comment: Yes. I should prove it. It is part of my doctoral research..

Comment: The integral is obtained when I am working on particle motion in an anisotropic medium (physics) you may not be interested in that matter.. It would be cool if you could please be of help thanks

Comment: I have found the solution. One simply should use the formula of Bessel function $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2\phi e^{ix\cos\phi}\, \mathrm{d}\phi = J_0(x)+J_2(x)$. Next, regularize the integral by multiplying by $e^{-\epsilon k}$ and taking the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ after evaluation of the integral over $k$. The third integral over $q$ follows forthwith.

Comment: @Federiko Notice that you've to find the integral in the right order, from the inside one to the ouside one not the other way around!